Tinymce won't allow me to type
I am building out a blog portion of my site and I am having a hell of a time with tinymce. When I try to type into the textarea it will not allow me to enter anything into the textarea.
Hoping someone has insight on this issue. Here is the code
Here is a simple example
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/API_KEY/tinymce/7/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea#basic-example',
        height: 500,
        plugins: [
            'advlist', 'autolink', 'lists', 'link', 'image', 'charmap', 'preview',
            'anchor', 'searchreplace', 'visualblocks', 'code', 'fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime', 'media', 'table', 'help', 'wordcount'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks | ' +
                'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
                'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
                'removeformat | help',
        content_style: 'body { font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size:16px }'
    });
</script>
<textarea id="basic-example">
  <p><img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" title="Tiny Logo" src="https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/images/logos/android-chrome-256x256.png" alt="TinyMCE Logo" width="128" height="128"></p>
  <h2 style="text-align: center;">Welcome to the TinyMCE editor demo!</h2>

  <h2>Got questions or need help?</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>Our <a href="https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/">documentation</a> is a great resource for learning how to configure TinyMCE.</li>
    <li>Have a specific question? Try the <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tinymce" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><code>tinymce</code> tag at Stack Overflow</a>.</li>
    <li>We also offer enterprise grade support as part of <a href="https://www.tiny.cloud/pricing">TinyMCE premium plans</a>.</li>
  </ul>

  <h2>A simple table to play with</h2>

  <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Really?</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>TinyMCE</td>
        <td>Free</td>
        <td>YES!</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Plupload</td>
        <td>Free</td>
        <td>YES!</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <h2>Found a bug?</h2>

  <p>
    If you think you have found a bug please create an issue on the <a href="https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues">GitHub repo</a> to report it to the developers.
  </p>

  <h2>Finally ...</h2>

  <p>
    Don't forget to check out our other product <a href="http://www.plupload.com" target="_blank">Plupload</a>, your ultimate upload solution featuring HTML5 upload support.
  </p>
  <p>
    Thanks for supporting TinyMCE! We hope it helps you and your users create great content.<br>All the best from the TinyMCE team.
  </p>
</textarea>

When I refresh the page, it initially says "Welcome to tinymce!" but then that message disappears and I can't type in the textarea. I have my apikey set up as documented and have tried every example they provide to no avail. I have ruled out browser issues with Chrome by attempting the same thing in Edge and Firefox.

If you remove the JS scripts, so it's just a plain HTML textarea, can you type in that? If not, it's a CSS issue: some other page element (or its "margin" or "padding" most likely) is invisibly sitting on top.
